# Change font encoding in itextsharp

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

My main purpose is displaying chinese font in a pdf.

The code i have to modify is

```
BackgroundColor = FontHelper.GetPdfColor(0, 0, 255),
FontColor = FontHelper.GetPdfColor(0, 255, 0),
FontStyle = FontStyle.NORMAL,
FontEncoding = FontEncodings.CP1252,
FontName = FontNames.TIMES_ROMAN
```

It seems that the issue is from FontEncodings.CP1252 or/and FontNames.TIMES_ROMAN, and i read all related post i think, but i can't find a simple solution.

I don't know enough the code i'm working on, so i would like to modify it the less possible.
I saw some solution with some FontSelector or something else and it's really different from what i have in my code, and hos to integrate it into my code.
Pretty much solution are also old, and potentially not up to date.

So, does exist a simple way to modify the font ?

Comment: Post some more code around your piece above! The way you create and use your font is relevant for the answer. Do you have the specific font you want to use as TTF file or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimal viable code-sample I could think of that shows how to change the font for a piece of text.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

   // setup
   PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(@"C:\Users\Joris Schellekens\Downloads\output.pdf");
   PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
   Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument);

   // font
   PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\comicbd.ttf");

   // paragraph
   Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet");
   para.SetFont(font);

   // add
   doc.Add(para);

   // close
   doc.Flush();
   doc.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally one of the simpliest way i found is

```
string ARIALUNI_TFF = @".\SimSun.ttf"  ;
bf=BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF,BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

A little adaptation of the joris answer.